# Automate Text to Columns with the Fixed Width setting?

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, fixed-width

I am trying to automate the text to columns feature in Excel. I want to use the default settings Excel chooses in the Fixed Width setting, because it always chooses the correct breaks with my particular datasets. When I record a macro for 2 different sheets that need to be parsed, and I choose the default fixed width setting, the macros look very different in terms of Array arguments. I figure there must be some way to just use Excel's default selection for array arguments, but can't seem to figure it out! Thanks in advance!

Macro1:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' -Macro1 Macro

Range("B10:B46").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B10"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(47, 1), Array(65, 1), Array(71, 1), 
Array(90, 1), _
    Array(95, 1), Array(113, 1), Array(126, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
End Sub
```

Macro2:

```
Sub Macro2()
' Macro2 Macro

Range("B8:B46").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B8"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(53, 1), Array(78, 1), Array(101, 1), 
Array(119, 1) _
    , Array(134, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
 End Sub
```

Comment: in Array - The first element is the column number (position), and the second element is based on format of that column.

Comment: Do you know how I can use the default parameters excel chooses when I go into the text column wizard and choose fixed width, in a macro?

Comment: @BigBen Just edited it. The code itself doesn't really matter just trying to see if what I am asking is even possible.

Comment: Here is a attempt to write something to figure out the defaults  >> http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/05/08/importing-fixed-width-text-files/   and it seems they gave up in the end

Comment: Thanks Pablo the link was informative. Looks like I need to find another solution.